# Are translation/pronunciation questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've come across a Hebrew word that I don't know how to pronounce. The word is
`השגחה`, which means `providence`. Sometimes, `השגחה פרטית`, `Divine Providence`.

After attempting to use automated transliteration tools, which produce something unpronounceable like `Hshgchh` and searching online for existing answers, I've determined that I'm going to need a human to help me with this one.

The question is, are questions like "How do I pronounce this Hebrew word" (Latinization) on topic provided attempts were made to find the pronunciation out on one's own? And if not, which SE site would be more appropriate for helping someone that speaks English to learn biblical Hebrew?

Comment: I would try in [chat]. (This doesn't even appear to be a Biblical word, but I or somebody else there would be happy to try to help you get the info you need. I suspect that it's not on topic on any extant SE site.)

Comment: I hate to be this guy, but https://www.google.ca/search?client=opera&hs=Hry&ei=dsgAXNrYMaq-jwTtxoCABw&q=how+to+pronounce+השגחה&oq=how+to+pronounce+השגחה&gs_l=psy-ab.3...12573.15565..16132...2.0..0.92.330.4......0....1..gws-wiz.......33i10i42.2Bk6oDMEIiw

Comment: BTW, Mi Yodeya chat is also sometimes helpful for questions like this. @Susan

Comment: There are also various different ways to pronounce Hebrew words (different traditions about certain vowel sounds and certain consonant sounds). The most common transliteration for the word השגחה is probably "hashgacha", wherein "h" corresponds to ה, "a" corresponds to the invisible vowel, "sh" corresponds to ש, "g" corresponds to ג, "a" corresponds to another invisible vowel, "ch" corresponds to ח, and "a" corresponds to ה.

Comment: Some minor variations include replacing the "ch" with "h", replacing the latter two "a" with "o", and adding "h" at the end (i.e. either "ah" or "oh". A couple of transliterations are mentioned in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divine_providence_in_Judaism).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are Hebrew language questions on-topic?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3521/are-hebrew-language-questions-on-topic)

Comment: You might want to visit these guys:  https://dailydoseofhebrew.com  or  http://www.ibiblio.org/bgreek/forum/viewforum.php?f=48