# Is this question asking for contemporary writers on topic?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question

**Question:** [To Interpret Koine Greek, which contemporary writers can be used for comparison?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/13970/423)

The following have been proposed by various community members thus far:

- This is a [list question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124450/166644) and thus not constructive for the SE Q&A format
- It's a [general reference question](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/635/423) (and a better fit for Wikipedia than SE)
- The question [belongs on meta](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/635/423), not main
- The question is too broad
- The question deals with hermeneutical tools and thus belongs on main

Is this question on topic? If not, why? Is it a better fit on meta? If so, why?

Comment: @majnemizdaen This question is really an continuation of the Lexicon/Concordance discussion, with "other references" thrown in to spice the debate. It belongs HERE as it involves site directives vs evidence to support a claim. It is a worthwhile question for Meta, and I'm sure you'll have some recommendations that will require a referendum.

Comment: @majnemizdaen The question(IMHO) has more to do with "What references are universally acceptable on BHSE", vs "What references can I most easily make my claim", which would be a "LMGTFY" question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### This is a list / general reference question and is off topic

The existing answer to the question demonstrates that it can easily be answered simply by linking to a few URLs containing lists of early works.

The [link given in the answer](http://www.hup.harvard.edu/features/loeb/timeline.html) contains sublinks at the top of the page for the additionally listed writers. I believe it meets [the criteria](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/638/423) of a 'general reference' question.

This sort of question is fine as a resource on meta, but is off topic on main.